# Setting the SelectIndex of combobox invoking SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is my code , List_sheet_name is a combo box

```
 List_sheet_name.Items.Clear();
            List_sheet_name.Items.Insert(0,"Select a table from Sheet");
            for (int i = 0; i < Sheets.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                List_sheet_name.Items.Add(Sheets.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
            }
            List_sheet_name.SelectedIndex = 0;
            //List_sheet_name.SelectedIndex = List_sheet_name.FindStringExact("Select a table from Sheet");
```

After setting the SelectIndex to zero (in last two lines) it is automatically invoking the SelectedIndexChanged event too. Can someone tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: An easy task - setting the "Select a table from Sheet" as default value

Comment: So, using SelectIndex is a valid option, what do you have in SelectedIndexChanged that you don't want it to be raised?

Comment: On SelectedIndexChanged my code is running to process the records , Which is getting invoked in advance by setting  List_sheet_name.SelectedIndex = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), the event reacts to all `SelectedIndex` changes. If you change the index to a new value which is equal to the previous one, the event won't be fired again, you need to call it manually.

If you don't want the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to be invoked when setting the `SelectedIndex`, you should check in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event whether the sender object (which is the `ComboBox`) is focused.

```
private void YourComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender as ComboBox).Focused)
        return;

    // ...your code
}
```

Comment: How to check whether the sender object is focused ?

Comment: You are wrong. By changing from 0 to 0 SelectedindexChanged will not be raised. To check, whether the control is focused is not reliable in this case

Comment: Thank you @Rekshino, I wasn't entirely sure about that and had to do a little research. I corrected it.

Comment: @Saurabh : If my solution satisfies your needs, please select it as an answer. I'm happy to help with any of your additional questions.:)

Answer (score 1):

Initially, it is -1. If you set to 0, then SelectedIndexChanged will be invoked.

Each time you set it to **ANOTHER** value, the SelectedIndexChanged will be raised. For set from codebehind you can use a variable bool _codeBehind, set it before you change SelectedIndex and evaluate in an Event handler

```
private bool _cmbSelIdxIntern = false;

void YourMeth()
{
    _cmbSelIdxIntern = true;
    cmbTest.SelectedIndex = 0;
    _cmbSelIdxIntern = false;
}

private void cmbTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_cmbSelIdxIntern)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to set it on -1 , but it does not set the desired value